# Handling Errors in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel

How can I handle errors and display a message from my request validation? When I submitted my inputs from form and goes to my controller, it automatically save the inputs even if it misses a single field.

Comment: We need to see what you have tried so far. How are you handling validation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a controller, You can specify the rules like below:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'title' => 'required|max:255',
        'body' => 'required',
    ],[
        'title.required' => 'Please enter title',
        'title.max' => 'Title must not be larger the 255 characters',  
        'title.required' => 'Please enter body',
    ]);

    // The form is valid, store in database...
}
```

In a view you can display errors like:

```
@if ($errors->any())
<div>
    @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
        {!! $error !!}<br/>
    @endforeach
</div>
```